# Does there exist an entire function such that $f\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does there exist an entire function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $f\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ ?

I tried through Taylor series expansion , also by contradictory way but I could not find out any contradiction...So I think $\exists$ such a function..But I am unable to find out an example of such function..

Comment: In general, look for Weierstrass factorization.

Comment: What is Weierstrass factorization ?

Comment: See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Comment: @  Frank Science ): Does there any condition such that without creating the function we can say that the existence of such a function ?

Comment: I suppose you're not interested in the obvious (but trivial) solution $f(z)=0$.

Comment: Yes yes...I want a non-constant function..

Comment: Is the function 
$f(z)=\sin\left(\pi(z^2+z\sqrt{z^2-4})\right)\sqrt{z^2-4}$ 
suitable?

Comment: @g.kov Is not $z=2$ a branch point of $f$ ?  So how can you say that $f$ is analytic ?